# sql query get multiple values from same column for one row

Tags: sql

I'm getting multiple rows per staff if they have multiple contact values, but I just want one row per staff listing their Last Name, First Name, Division Name, Email and Phone.

So it should like like this

```
    First Name    Last Name    Division     Email                  Phone
       Test          Guy         Exec     test@gmail.com        555-5555
```

Here is what I have, but it's not working:

```
    SELECT sr.LastName, sr.FirstName, dd.Name, 
        Email = (select sc.ContactValue FROM StaffContactInformation as sc
         INNER JOIN StaffRoster as roster on sc.StaffID = roster.ID
         where sc.ContactTypeID = 3 and roster.ID = sr.ID),
Phone = (SELECT sc1.ContactValue FROM StaffContactInformation as sc1 
        INNER JOIN StaffRoster as roster on sc1.StaffID = roster.ID
        where sc1.ContactTypeID = 1) 
    FROM StaffRoster as sr
    left join dictDivisions as dd on sr.DivisionID = dd.Id  
    left join StaffContactInformation as sci on sr.ID = sci.StaffID
    inner join dictStaffContactTypes as dsct on sci.ContactTypeID = dsct.ID 
    where (sr.Active = 1 and sr.isContractor = 0 )
    ORDER BY sr.LastName, sr.FirstName
```

I solved it with the following query:

```
    SELECT sr.LastName, sr.FirstName, dd.Name, 
        Email = (select sc.ContactValue FROM StaffContactInformation as sc
         INNER JOIN StaffRoster as roster on sc.StaffID = roster.ID
         where sc.ContactTypeID = 3 and roster.ID = sr.ID),
Phone = (SELECT sc.ContactValue FROM StaffContactInformation as sc 
        INNER JOIN StaffRoster as roster on sc.StaffID = roster.ID
        where sc.ContactTypeID = 1 and roster.ID = sr.ID) 
    FROM StaffRoster as sr
    left join dictDivisions as dd on sr.DivisionID = dd.Id 
    where (sr.Active = 1 and sr.isContractor = 0 )
    ORDER BY sr.LastName, sr.FirstName
```

Comment: Are they multiple **duplicate** rows?  If so, just use `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are all the values for each column for Mr Test Guy the same? Can you show us the result you are getting?

Comment: they are not duplicate rows, staff can have multiple contacts in contact table because there are multiple contact types, so they show up once for each contact type.  I was trying to write this query to just show phone and email in the same row, so one row per staff

Comment: using sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are selecting `email` and `phone` in subqueries these two joins are probably unnecessary:

```
left join StaffContactInformation as sci on sr.ID = sci.StaffID
inner join dictStaffContactTypes as dsct on sci.ContactTypeID = dsct.ID
```

Because of them you are getting as many rows as contacts for specific person.

Final query might look like:

```
SELECT sr.LastName, sr.FirstName, dd.Name, 
    Email = (
        select sc.ContactValue FROM StaffContactInformation as sc
        INNER JOIN StaffRoster as roster on sc.StaffID = roster.ID
        where sc.ContactTypeID = 3 and roster.ID = sr.ID
    ),
    Phone = (
        SELECT sc1.ContactValue FROM StaffContactInformation as sc1 
        INNER JOIN StaffRoster as roster on sc1.StaffID = roster.ID
        where sc1.ContactTypeID = 1
    ) 
FROM StaffRoster as sr
left join dictDivisions as dd on sr.DivisionID = dd.Id  
where (sr.Active = 1 and sr.isContractor = 0 )
ORDER BY sr.LastName, sr.FirstName
```

Comment: this put me in the right direction, I solved it by taking out the two joins you listed at the top, then I had to fix the subqueries.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're running SQL Server 2005+, you can use a pivot table.  Here I declare a CTE to encapsulate the pivot table with which you can join into the rest of your query:

```
;with ContactInfo( StaffId, Email, Phone )
as
(
    select
        sci.StaffID
        , [3] Email
        , [1] Phone
    from
        StaffContractInformation sci
        PIVOT( MAX(ContactValue) for ContactTypeId in ( [3], [1] ) PivotTable

)

SELECT 
    sr.LastName, 
    sr.FirstName, 
    dd.Name, 
    ci.Email,
    ci.Phone
FROM 
    StaffRoster as sr
    left join dictDivisions as dd 
     on sr.DivisionID = dd.Id  
    left join ContactInfo ci
     on sr.ID = ci.StaffID
  --  inner join dictStaffContactTypes as dsct 
     --on sci.ContactTypeID = dsct.ID 
where 
    sr.Active = 1 
    and sr.isContractor = 0
ORDER BY 
    sr.LastName, 
    sr.FirstName
```