# SQL Multiple Values in Same Column

Tags: sql, oracle

Provided this sort of db structure how might one write a query to find only movies that have both male and female patrons?

```
movie
  movID
  name
ticket
  TID
  movID
  patronID
patron
  PID
  gender
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499472/sql-query-get-multiple-values-from-same-column-for-one-row

Comment: What do you have so far? If you can join the tables to get effectively all patrons for all movies, you can count the number of distinct genders for each one?

Comment: I've gotten to joining the tables but I'm unsure of how to go about the counting step you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say do two queries to get all male patrons and female patrons and then join those based on movID:

```
WITH malePatrons AS

( 
   SELECT name, m.movID 
   FROM movie JOIN ticket tic ON movie.movID = tic.movID 
   JOIN patron pat ON pat.PID = tic.patronID
   WHERE pat.gender = "male"
), femalePatrons AS

(
   SELECT name, m.movID 
   FROM movie JOIN ticket tic ON movie.movID = tic.movID 
   JOIN patron pat ON pat.PID = tic.patronID
   WHERE pat.gender = "female"
)
   Select * FROM malePatrons JOIN femalePatrons fem ON malePatrons.movID = fem.movID
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to query the tables multiple times. My comment may have been a but too obscure, but I was trying to hint you towards something like:

```
select m.name
from movie m
join ticket t on t.movid = m.movid
join patron p on p.pid = t.patronid
group by m.movid, m.name
having count(distinct p.gender) = 2;
```

This looks for all tickets for all movies, and counts the number of distinct genders of the patron who had those ticketss. (This assumes there are only two genders of course, for simplicity; if you have more then you can add a filter). The `having` clause checks that the count is 2. If a movie only has male or female patrons, not both, the count would be 1, and it would be excluded from the result.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/40166/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select m.movieid, name, count(distinct(gender))as Count
from

MOVIE m
JOIN
Ticket t
on m.movid=t.movid
JOIN
patron P
on 
t.patronid=p.Pid


GROUP BY  m.movieid, name
HAVING count(distinct(gender)) > 1
```